# Including something implausible in an otherwise realistic story

Tags: fiction, paranormal

Let's say I'm writing a story that isn't a fantasy story, it's more of a realistic thriller. However, I want to include a character who has psychic powers like telepathy and psychokinesis.

Is it possible to include a character like that, and still have a realistic story?  If so, how should it be handled?  Are there good reasons not to do this or any particular pitfalls to look out for?

Comment: I'm a little unclear what you're asking. What does "isn't entirely supernatural" mean? Either your character genuinely has powers or genuinely doesn't. Are you trying to write your story such that your reader has to decide if the character does or doesn't have powers because either explanation is ultimately plausible?

Comment: Sorry I know that my title isn't very clear. Basically what I want is to know, how to include a character from where it's obvious that he has such abilities... He is a character in a story which isn't really supernatural at all.

Comment: Still not clear. If your character has Powers, then your story is not in the "realistic" genre. You can call it Urban Fantasy, which is when there are supernatural/fantasy elements in an otherwise realistic setting (for example, the entire Marvel Cinematic Universe to date). There may not be *other* supernatural goings-on, which is fine, but if he has telepathy and psychokinesis, it's a supernatural story. So is your question about how to write a character with powers in an urban fantasy setting?

Comment: Heya! This question is somewhat unclear and fairly borderline for us; I'm going to put it on hold and we'll see if we can make this workable. Primarily: **what problem are you having?** What's keeping you from continuing to write this character, as you imagine them?

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to find a better title.

Comment: I have edited this question and nominated for reopening

Answer (score 2):

An excellent statistician maybe, someone who can predict different events given certain elements.

Or someone remarkably observant (think Sherlock Holmes), such that what seems like supernatural powers to the "avarage" individual is just 'watch and conclude' for this person.